# Domain ownership not verified Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

My App Play Store console showing many errors and users download not showing in play store also and ratings.

Domain ownership not verified
Users will not go directly to your app from links associated with this path, but will see the app picker or be directed to the web browser. Once you have fixed these issues and published a new version, users need to update their app before the links will work.

[image]

Domain ownership not verified
Users will not go directly to your app from links associated with this path, but will see the app picker or be directed to the web browser. Once you have fixed these issues and published a new version, users need to update their app before the links will work.
FIX DOMAIN ISSUES
[image]

[image]